# PHP DOMDocument not returning or loading first elements

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a problem with loading my XML document. The XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE gallery [
<!ELEMENT gallery (category*)>
<!ELEMENT category (image*)>
<!ELEMENT image (title,comment,password,owner,rating)>
<!ELEMENT title ANY>
<!ELEMENT comment ANY>
<!ELEMENT password ANY>
<!ELEMENT owner ANY>
<!ELEMENT rating ANY>
<!ATTLIST category name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST image date CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<gallery>
    <category name="entertainment">
        <image date="monday">
            <title>1</title>
            <comment>2</comment>
            <password>3</password>
            <owner>4</owner>
            <rating>5</rating>
        </image>
        <image date="friday">
            <title>11</title>
            <comment>22</comment>
            <password>33</password>
            <owner>44</owner>
            <rating>55</rating>
        </image>
    </category>
    <category name="education">
    </category>
    <category name="relax">
    </category>
    <category name="sporting">
    </category>
</gallery>
```

And my PHP to print this XML is

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->validateOnParse = true;
    $doc->load(ROOT_PATH."xml/data.xml");

    if($doc->validate()) {
        print_r($doc->saveHTML());

    }
    else echo 'Not Validated ';
```

And the result is

```
2 3 4 5 22 33 44 55
```

By the way, I cannot understand why the first elements are skipped. I have problems to select element like this

```
$category = $doc->getElementById('entertainment');

if (!$category){
    echo 'not found';
}
```

which returns:

```
not found
```

Comment: Are you doing this in a browser? View the browser's _page source_ to see the XML structure. If you are just seeing `2 3 5 22 33 44 55` it is probably because the browser is interpreting XML as HTML markup. What you have does work to dump the XML back to the screen: http://ideone.com/WtzeKM

Comment: And `entertainment` isn't found because there is no element with `id='entertainment'` though you do have `name='entertainment'`.

Comment: Thank for sugestions. But my browser print this xml in html correctly. Witch is 1 2 3 4 5 11 22 33 44 55. And xml raw file in browser is correct too.

Comment: If you have more code than posted above, please include the relevant parts. There is nothing above which would prevent the `<title>` elements from printing, and indeed you can see in the test I linked that they do.  Use `$doc->getElementsByTagName('title')` for example to get all the `<title>` nodes

Comment: It makes no sense to use `saveHTML` on this XML document because it doesn't represent HTML. And I suspect you're failing to select the entertainment category because your DTD doesn't indicate anywhere that the `name` attribute represents an ID.

Comment: Yes calling echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue; will print 1. But still my problem with printing entire xml and selecting by ID is not solved. Thank you.

Comment: Is this DTD declaration of ID not valid?

Comment: Thank @JLRishe but calling print_r($doc->saveXML()); is still the same. I dont know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to use saveHTML on this XML document because it doesn't represent HTML. A `<title>` element has a semantic meaning in HTML and it is an element that doesn't get displayed on the page, so that is probably why you can't see the 1 and the 11.

I suspect you're failing to select the entertainment category because your DTD doesn't indicate anywhere that the name attribute represents an ID. You'd need to have something like this in your DTD:

```
<!ATTLIST category name ID #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my headcache :) Yes the title was not printing because special meaning. I have changed this element to another name and it works now. And the declaration like you sugest is right too. I can select now by ID. Thank again.